In Tikz, how to make a command that will pave a zone of my page with N*M of the same rectangular node?
Consider that I have a command that produces a Tikz node:
% First parameter: node name
% Second parameter: node width
% Third parameter: node height
\newcommand{\makenode}[3]{
    \node (#1) [draw, thick, minimum width=#2, minimum height=#3] {This is some text.}
}

I would like to create a command \newcommand{\makegrid}[3] that would produce a grid of $N \times M$ of this node (the result should be centered on the current page), each copy separated from the previous one by a distance $d$ (if $d=0$, then there should be no distance between nodes, they should just come one after another).
% First parameter: number of horizontal nodes
% Second parameter: number of vertical nodes
% Third parameter: distance (horizontal and vertical) between a node and the next one (0cm = no distance between nodes)
\newcommand{\makegrid}[3]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, shift={(current page.center)}]
        % ! DO SOMETHING HERE ! %
        \makenode{mynode}{5cm}{3cm}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

Currently, I have this code that just draws a single node:
% Preamble
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

% First parameter: node name
% Second parameter: node width
% Third parameter: node height
\newcommand{\makenode}[3]{
    \node (#1) [draw, thick, minimum width=#2, minimum height=#3] {This is some text.};
}

% First parameter: number of horizontal nodes
% Second parameter: number of vertical nodes
% Third parameter: distance (horizontal and vertical) between a node and the next one (0cm = no distance between nodes)
\newcommand{\makegrid}[3]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, shift={(current page.center)}]
        % ! DO SOMETHING HERE ! %
        \makenode{mynode}{5cm}{3cm}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

% Main code
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\makegrid{3}{5}{0.5cm}
\end{document}

QUESTIONS:

How to make it work and generate the grid of $N\times M$ nodes (I am looking for a simple and compact code, nothing super complex). Commands can be changed.
Bonus if the node type can be an input of the \makegrid function itself, if I have several node types (for example to produce a page of first node type, and a page of a second node type).

If there are easier ways to do that in Tikz, with a different interface (maybe there is already something in Tikz that produces the desired result, I'm completely open to it).

Sounds like a TikZ \matrix would be easiest for this.

Like this?
I use to check the centering.
\AddToHook{shipout/background}[line]{
    \put (0.5cm,-0.5\textheight){\rule{1pt}{0.5\textheight}}
    \put (0.cm,-0.5\textheight){\rule{0.5\textwidth}{1pt}}
    }

I don't know how to explain \vspace{-10pt}
EDIT: with this post New environment to vertically center text
I had \setlength{\topskip}{0pt}%. I replace also \leavevmode by \hrule height0pt depth0pt width1pt
% Preamble
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe,margin=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newlength{\mylength}
\settoheight{\mylength}{a}
\tikzset{%
    mywidth/.initial=5cm,
    myheight/.initial=3cm,
    mynode/.style={%
        draw,
        thick, 
        minimum width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mywidth}, 
        minimum height=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/myheight}},
    }
\newcommand{\makegrid}[3]{%
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299522/new-environment-to-vertically-center-text
    \setlength{\topskip}{0pt}%
    % \leavevmode
    \hrule height0pt depth0pt width1pt
    %  \Huge
    % \vspace{-10pt}% DELETE with \topskip=0pt
    \vfill%
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}%
            \foreach \j  in {1,...,#2}%
                {%
                    \node [mynode](N\i-\j) at ([shift={(\i*#3,-\j*#3)}]\i*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mywidth},-\j*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/myheight}) {(\i,\j)};% or This is some text.
                }%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \vfill%
}

% Main code
\begin{document}
\AddToHook{shipout/background}[line]{
    \put (0.5cm,-0.5\textheight){\rule{1pt}{0.5\textheight}}
    \put (0.cm,-0.5\textheight){\rule{0.5\textwidth}{1pt}}
    }
\thispagestyle{empty}
\makegrid{3}{5}{0.5cm}
\end{document}


